# Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\izul\Aplikasi Konversi\convert.php on line 15

Tags: php, forms, handler

i try make picture handler form, but get this error

**Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\App\convert.php on line 15**

this full code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>File Upload Converter Result</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
    <header>
        <h1>File Upload Converter Result</h1>
    </header>
    <?php
    $isi = fopen($_FILES[$_GET["myfiles"]]["tmp_name"], 'r');
    ?>
    <div class="badan">
        <p>File Name :</p>
        <?php
            $values = $_GET["myfiles"];
            if (is_array($values) || is_object($values))
                {
                    foreach ($values as $value)
                    {
                        echo("<p>". $value ."</p>");
                    }
                }
        ?>
        <p>File Old Type : <?php echo($_GET["tipe1"]) ?></p>
        <p>File New Type : <?php echo($_GET["tipe2"]) ?></p>

        <img src="<?php echo($isi) ?>" alt="<?php echo($isi) ?>">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

can someone help me? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_FILES[$_GET["myfiles"]]["tmp_name"]
```

should be

```
$_FILES["myfiles"]["tmp_name"]
```

---

And if you're having multiple files (what the name "myfiles" suggests), then you need to threat that whole thing as an array:

```
foreach($_FILES["myfiles"]["tmp_name"] as $filename) {

$isi = fopen($filename, 'r');

}

unset($filename);
```

---

That however:

```
<img src="<?php echo($isi) ?>" alt="<?php echo($isi) ?>">
```

Makes no sense. Fopen returns a file pointer resource, not any text content. To read the content of a file, you can use:

```
$isi = file_get_contents($filename);
```

But even then, using the content as the src-attribute or alt-attribute doesn't make any sense. With the src-attribute you link to a file and the alt-attribute displays an alternative text if, for whatever reason, the file cannot be loaded.